# patch review web based system

Tags: django, git, patch

How can I created a patch review system on a website?
Basically on my server I have the repository and when a patch is submitted through a form I want to display in the web interface the patch in the context of the git repo.
What is available out there to help me accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a web-based submit and review system for git, have a look at [Gerrit](http://source.android.com/source/life-of-a-patch.html) from Google.